# how to collect urls with connection refused error in scrapy without using logfile

Tags: scrapy, twisted

i'm writing a scrapy crawler, at the end of the logfile scrapy stats,  'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError':2, i want to collected these two urls in a list and print them out, is there a way to do it without saving and parsing logfile after the crawling for all urls is done?

Comment: You should be able to make a custom logger and react when you get a connection error. https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#scrapy.logformatter.LogFormatter

Comment: hi, thanks for commenting! i figured that much, now im able to collect what i want into a self.refused attribute within scrapy crawler, working on how to return this attribute outside of scrapy to be used in the following python codes, any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what you plan to do with the URLs afterward. Usually, you can't do much when you get Connection refused errors. But the first thing that comes to mind is sending the URLs to a queue once the log event is triggered.

Comment: what is the queue you mentioned? is it a python or scrapy thing? i ended up using a python global variable to pass the urls, errors etc out of scrapy and into the remaining python script